# Set schema automatically after auto-insert

Tags: nxml

I have auto-insert-mode configured to insert a basic XML file in nxml-mode, but nxml-mode is then still configured to use an empty schema, as if the file was still empty. How can I automatically make nxml-mode use the correct schema corresponding to the template? Set schema automatically in the menus does work, but I want to run this automatically.

Answer (score 1):

I never used that but looking at the documentation and code, I think
the function you're talking about is `rng-auto-set-schema` from
`rng-validate-mode`.  This minor mode is enabled by default with
`nxml-mode`.

Here is what `auto-insert-mode` does:

```el
  (if auto-insert-mode
      (add-hook 'find-file-hook 'auto-insert)
    (remove-hook 'find-file-hook 'auto-insert)))
```

The problem is probably that `find-file-hook` is considered only after the
major mode has been selected, so `rng-auto-set-schema` is called
before your snippet is actually inserted in the buffer.

Since `auto-insert` apparently does not provide any hooks, I see two ways to work around that:

- advise `auto-insert` so that after inserting, it calls
  `rng-auto-set-schema` if major mode is `nxml-mode`,
- add a hook at the end of `find-file-hook` to do the same thing.

Here's a tentative for the second solution:

```el
(defun my-set-schema-if-nxml ()
  (if (eq major-mode 'nxml-mode)
      (rng-auto-set-schema)))

(add-hook 'find-file-hook 'my-set-schema-if-nxml t)
```

Comment: I'd love to see someone implement a more generic solution: when the buffer starts empty, setup an after-change-function which tries to set the schema.  And remove this after-change-function as soon as we have enough data to determine the schema (i.e. as soon as we see the end of the first opening tag).